# MMS service app pool name is incorrect

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, iis

I've created a managed metadata service with PowerShell:

```
New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name "SPService" -Account CONTOSO\Admin

New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name "MetadataServiceApp" -ApplicationPool "SPService" -DatabaseName "Sharepoint_Service_MSS"

New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Name "MetadataServiceProxy" -ServiceApplication "MetadataServiceApp" -DefaultProxyGroup
```

I used "SPService"  as the of the application pool, but when I look in IIS the app pool has the name: "64a50212a67a46878c975563efd332b4". Is this default behavior or is there another way to set the app pool with the correct name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately this is default behavior. But there are ways around it. You can’t rename AppPools in the IIS, but you can create another AppPool and move the applications to the new AppPool. It’s a tedious work and you shouldn’t do this unless it’s absolutely necessary.

Instead, fire up you SharePoint Management shell and type:

```
Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | select Name, Id
```

You will see the Name and the GUID – which is the same GUID as the ones in IIS. Just compare the two, and you know which is which. (IIS AppPool is represented without slashes [-])

[image]

Another way is to right-click the GUID AppPool in the IIS and select View Applications.

[image]

In the Physical Path row, you often see which AppPool this is.

[image]